# Masking Two Textures in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I have two different textures. One is Colored one and other is simply alpha image I want to mask both Image Textures. How I can do that in Metal Shader Language. one texture is 128*128 size other is 256*256 in size. I want the mask texture in the size of 128*128.

```
fragment float4 fragmentShaderone(VertexOut params[[stage_in]],
                                                              texture2d<float, access::sample>srcTexture [[texture(0)]],
                                                              texture2d<float, access::sample> maskTexture [[texture(1)]])
{

    constexpr sampler defaultSampler;

    float  srcColor = float4(texture.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates)))  * float4(1,0,0,40.0/255.0);

    float4 maskColor = float4(texture4.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.textureCoordinates))) ;

    return srcColor * maskColor

}
```

Here In sampling Texture I am using same coordinates for mask and source image.

Comment: You can just take the `.rgb` components from the source and the `.a` from the mask (or its inverse `1.0 - maskColor.a`, depending on the nature of the mask).

Comment: @KenThomases https://imgur.com/OB4Gph5  The actual need is explained in this picture

Comment: @Ruban4Axis did you manage to do it?